# How can I delete one field of entity in Moqui?

Tags: sql-delete, moqui

My question is how can I delete one field of entity in Moqui which that field is deleted from database? Suppose I wrote one entity and define its field but after some time understand its false and I want delete that specific field from database how can I do this in Moqui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly, you need to delete it in your database.
- Then, modify your XML entity definition.
- Then, run `gradlew load` for reloading new database schema.